# What would make this directory not group-writable on HDFS?

Tags: java, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

With this code:

```
fileSystem.mkdirs(new Path(path), new FsPermission((short)0774));
```

or this code:

```
fileSystem.mkdirs(new Path(path), new FsPermission(FsAction.ALL, FsAction.ALL, FsAction.READ_EXECUTE));
```

why would the created directory not be group-writable?  The same issue exists for files.  The owner perms are set to rwx, but group is set to r--.

This code is running under cdh3u3.

Comment: You don't have `dfs.permissions = false` in hdfs-site.xml, right?

Comment: @CharlesMenguy: Ah, I do indeed.  I'll try again with it set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your hdfs-site.xml and set the following property:

```
dfs.permissions = true
```

If this is set to `false`, switching from one parameter value to the other does not change the mode, owner or group of files or directories. More information on permissions [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/hdfs_permissions_guide.html).

Once this is done, don't forget to restart your cluster since this is a datanode configuration change.

Comment: So, there's a little more relevant background, now that I understand the issue.  We have our shared environments, but we also have our local environments, where dfs.permissions = false.  The change I made on my local environment was to change from the default of 022 dfs.umask=002.  In the shared environment, we have security set up.  I'll do a little more research on how we're configured there, but that's got us pointed in the right direction.  Thank you!

Comment: Now I could set dfs.permissions=true locally, but then hadoop starts enforcing security, and I'd like to leave it wide open for local development.

Comment: Actually, dfs.umaskmode replaces dfs.umask.